# Ehcache RMI Replication Not Working.Need to know how to visualise replication?

Tags: caching, replication, ehcache

I have setup my *ehcache replication using RMI*.However, **I don't see any replication happening** neither do I get any error.
Can you please take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong?I have tried both automatic and manual mode of discovery but to no avail.

I have **enabled TRACE logging for net.sf hierarchy** but I don't see any activity**.Can you please let me know how to visualise the replication,via logs?What category to add etc.**

**My test scenario**
I access jsp on host1 and thereafter on host2.When I then go back to host1 I expect to see some logs of replication or the replicated value coming back which I don't see.
Any help is appreciated.I have been struggling with this for quite sometime now.

**My config is as follows**

**on host 1**

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//host2:40001/reportsCache"/>


<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory 
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" 
properties="hostname=host1, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=3000"/>
```

**on host 2**

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//host1:40001/reportsCache"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory 
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" 
properties="hostname=host2, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=3000"/>
```

**My ehcache config is as follows**

```
<cache name="reportsCache"
     maxElementsInMemory="1000"
     maxElementsOnDisk="100"
     eternal="false"
     overflowToDisk="true"
     timeToIdleSeconds="15"
     timeToLiveSeconds="15"
     statistics="true">

<cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
  properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,
             replicatePuts=true,
             replicatePutsViaCopy=true,
             replicateUpdates=true,
             replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,
             replicateRemovals=true" />
<bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"/>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to enable logging?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant logger used is called `net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer`, where you have to enable `DEBUG` level.

How to configure the logger really depends on your logging framework. For log4j you would use something like the following in your `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer=DEBUG
```

For log4j2 put the following in your `log4j2.xml`:

```
<loggers>
   ...
   <logger name="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer" level="debug" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There was no problem as such.I think my testing was a bit off the mark.**
I had the same jsp being accessed from two nodes(by 2 diff browser sessions) and was relying on my logs to see for cues regarding replication.I just changed my approach to see the content/data on the jsp and i see that the other node fetches the same data after a hit on the first node has been updated.So this is enough for my test.
**however,I'm still curious to know how to see any logs about replication events?**
I turned on a instance of ehcache-debugger too but i didn't see any thing coming up.
If anyone here can tell me how to see the logs pertaining to replication events that would be great.For the record,I have set the log level at TRACE for the net.sf package.

Comment: You can use jconsole from your java bin directory to see your ehcache objects